# Kyslik/column-sortable doesn't work with withCount

Tags: laravel

```
$users = Category::sortable()->withCount('posts')->paginate(5);
```

This is my query to fetch user `withCount('posts')`

I am using `Kyslik/column-sortable`, but it can't sort with `posts_count`.

I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Add following code in the model

```
protected $sortableAs = ['posts_count'];
```

> Note: no camelcase for the variable name here: postsCount doesn't work, posts_count does.

See [Github issue](https://github.com/Kyslik/column-sortable/issues/49) for more information.